# Removing a recursive folder that's not recursive in windows fails with "Source Path Too Long"

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, path, remove

I seem to have managed to get an *Application Data* folder recurse into itself somehow, doesn't *look* recursive but somehow still is and now I find myself unable to remove that folder. The folder itself is merely a subfolder in a backup folder from an old pc. It isn't used anymore in any way.

Current folder name is

```
C:\DWI00672\toremove\brhi\AppData\local
```

*(I renamed Documents and Settings to toremove)*

**Following I have tried**

- Delete in explorer.

  [image]
- `rmdir /s /q .`
- `chkdsk`. This reports a `Windows may not detect all cycles on your volume because the directory structure is too deep.`
- `robocopy` to mirror an empty folder into the recursive one. This crashed robocopy with a stack overflow: `STACK_OVERFLOW_c00000fd_Robocopy.exe!RoboPrune`
- Rename `Application Data` recursively to `t` to shorten the path length. This stops with the message that the fully qualified name must be less than 260 characters

  ```
  $current = gci "C:\DWI00672\toremove\brhi\AppData\local" -Force 
  while ($true) {
    $current.FullName
    if ($current.BaseName -ne "t") {Rename-Item -Path $current.FullName t -ErrorAction Inquire -Force }
    $current = gci "$($current.Parent.FullName)\t" -Force -ErrorAction Inquire 
  }
  ```
- Download `TeraCopy` and try it having remove the folder.
- `subst` into the folder structure to furter shorten the path using the Powershell script. After drive `K:`, I gave up.[image]
- `junction -s` from sysinterals but this finds no reparse points.
  [image]
- `dir /s c:\DWI00672\toremove\brhi\AppData\Local` is currently listing 330 Dir(s)
- `dir /al /s c:\DWI00672\toremove\brhi\AppData\Local` to list the Reparse Points is returning File Not Found
- `rm -f -d c:\DWI00672\toremove\brhi\AppData\Local` from Cygwin executed as current user, administrator and as system *(psexec -s -i cmd)*. The all return `rm: cannot unlink 'local': Not owner`. The owner of the Local folder is my current user.

Comment: It's possible that somewhere under the Local folder (in one of it's many sub folders, or sub sub etc) there is a SymLink called Local to the real Local folder. This would certainly create a cycle. (See the clue in the message "cannot unlink 'local'" - may not be correct but it is suggestive.)

Comment: Possible but `dir /al /s` and/or `junction -s` should have found those. Let's assume that's right, any idea how to remove the folder structure?

Comment: This question's subject matter attracts a number of very persistent spammers. Protecting the question prevents them from posting.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I can't comment.

But, you could try to use robocopy to mirror an empty directory to C:\DWI00672, then remove the directory.

So:

1. mkdir C:\empty
2. robocopy C:\empty C:\DWI00672 /PURGE
3. rmdir C:\empty
4. rmdir C:\DWI00672

Robocopy doesn't use the same system calls that have the 248 character limit. But it might have an upper character limit I'm not aware of.

I just tried it on my system, it worked just fine (this had a folder structure of around 400 characters).

Comment: I tried and listed that, it didn't work: *robocopy to mirror an empty folder into the recursive one*. I just tried it again with the /PURGE parameter but it crashes with a stack overflow.Following is the failure bucket id: `STACK_OVERFLOW_c00000fd_Robocopy.exe!RoboPrune``